# Saving Proxy Settings from different networks

Tags: browser, networking, proxy

I go to different clients and they all have their networks with different proxy settings. So I'm always having to change the proxy settings and saving the info in a notebook, and it becomes a pain after a while.

So, any good way to save all those proxies and have them recognize the network I'm on and load up?

Currently I maintain two: one in IE for clients, and none in Firefox for when I'm at home.

And I think the last network I was on asked me to save the proxy and I think it went to system settings. But I don't know much about networking.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/45871/can-i-make-windows-7-change-my-proxy-settings-based-on-my-network-connection)

[Proxy Switcher](http://www.proxyswitcher.com/download.html) offers that capability, for automatic it looks like you'd need buy the Pro version.

Firefox extension [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2464/) would be an option for Firefox, but doesn't really meet your requirements.

If you can script, you can do it yourself.  [How to write a proxy config script](https://superuser.com/questions/45871/can-i-make-windows-7-change-my-proxy-settings-based-on-my-network-connection)